# can a user see a list of private/locked channels on SLACK?

Tags: slack

If there are private channels on slack, can a user without admin rights see the list of those channels?

Answer (score 4):

No.

A Slack user - including admins and owners - can only see non-public channels (e.g. private channels, direct messages channels, private group chat, etc.) they are of member of.

It's one of Slack's security features that even admins can not see or join private channels of others.

Comment: There's absolutely no way for an admin to join a private channel, add a user to a private channel, or at least list the private channels that they are not a member of?

Comment: Correct. It's one of the core elements of Slack's security architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on "Channels" gives any user a list of all channels, including private ones that they are a member of. The list can be filtered to show private channels only.

Comment: A user is able to see private channels if he's a member of these channels. Others private channels are not listed.

Comment: Thank you! I have edited my answer.